# Java GUI is blank

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I began building a GUI using net-beans GUI builder and since then I have decided to try rebuild it without the GUI builder, as I think it is probably bad practise and doesn't really allow me to learn anything with swing.

I've tried to start rebuilding the GUI but when I run the program a blank GUI without any features pops up, was wondering if anyone could help me as to why it is doing this? My program consists of two classes used for separate windows (Frames(?)).

My code is as follows:

```
package com.company;
public class Form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private javax.swing.JButton btnComboBox;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboOne;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;

public Form1() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    comboOne = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btnComboBox = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jLabel2.setText("SELECT PRINTER:");

    comboOne.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[]{"Printer 1", "Printer 2", "Printer 3", "Printer 4"}));

    comboOne.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comboOneActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnComboBox.setText("GO");
    btnComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnComboBoxActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

}

private void comboOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Object selected = comboOne.getSelectedItem().toString();

}

private void btnComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // Opens a new form, converts the object selected in combobox too a string
    // Passes string to openMe on form 2

    Form2 f2 = new Form2(comboOne.getSelectedItem().toString());

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Form1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Form 2:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Form2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jta;

public Form2() {
    initComponents();
}
public Form2(String message) {

    initComponents();
    jta.append(" Printer selected: " + message + "\n");
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jta = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Console");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11));
    jLabel3.setText("");

    jta.setColumns(20);
    jta.setRows(50);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jta);

}

public void openMe(String message) {

    /*java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Form2().setVisible(true);

        }
    });*/

    System.out.println("----- Console Output ------");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Printer selected: " + message);
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("\n");

}
}
```

Any help appreciated as always

Comment: You don't add your components to a container related to the frame, have a look at Swing tutorials for a starter : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: @Berger Ok, thanks

Comment: @Berger please transform comment into an answer to let author accept it.

Comment: @Riduidel : well I don't consider this as a complete answer, as it is just a pointer and doesn't directly solves the above problem.But thanks :)

Comment: The question should actually be closed as off-topic due to a trivial error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make the following changes and see the results:

**Step 1:**

Insert following lines as last statements of the method `private void initComponents()` of `Form1.java`:

```
private void initComponents() {

  // existing code

  this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));       
  this.add(jLabel2);
  this.add(comboOne);
  this.add(btnComboBox);
}
```

**Step 2:**

Replace the existing definition by the following one in `Form1.java`:

```
private void btnComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 Form2 f2 = new Form2(comboOne.getSelectedItem().toString());       
 f2.setSize(250, 300);
 f2.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
 f2.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Step 3:**

Replace existing `main` method of `Form1.java` by following one:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
                form1.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                form1.setSize(300, 200);
                form1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                form1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });    
}
```

**Step 4:**

Search `jLabel3.setText("")` in `Form2.java` and replace it by `jLabel3.setText("Output")`.

**Step 5:**

Insert following lines as last statements of method `private void initComponents()` of `Form2.java`:

```
private void initComponents() {

  // existing code

  this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
  JPanel topPanel=new JPanel();
  this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));

  this.add(jLabel1);
  this.add(jLabel3);

  this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  this.add(jScrollPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

The output of `Form1.java` on my system is:

[image]

And the output of `Form2.java` on my system is:

[image]

Comment: Hi! First I really appriciate you taking the time, the first form is running fine now, yet when I select the option from the combo and press the go button.. i get an error and the program stops running.

Comment: getting error - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException - i will keep playing and let you know if i get it working

Comment: WORKED. appreciate that !

Comment: I am really glad to help you solve the problem. Your effort is also noteworthy.